# Responsive 2 column css layout with one column overflow horizontal scroll

Tags: css, responsive-design, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I've got a responsive 2 column layout going on. The first column is a fixed width, while the second one is using the css `calc` property to subtract certain pixels from its 100% width.

What I want the second column to do is to scroll horizontally, regardless of the screen size or width of it. I threw together a quick pen to illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/trevanhetzel/pen/nbdIt

As you can see, the second column has multiple `.thing` divs inside of it that are floated left and have a defined width. What I DON'T want is for these `.thing` divs to drop down to another line when they run out of room inside the second column.

How can this be achieved? I tried messing the `overflow` property, but I think I might need another container div with some different positioning properties or something. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/lutjb

The solution to this is:

1. Change `.thing` from `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;`. This keeps those elements in line, but also keeps them in flow so the parent element acknowledges it has children
2. Give `section` a `white-space: nowrap;` property. This prevents the `.thing` elements from going to another line.
3. Give `section` an `overflow-x: auto` property. This allows the div to be scrolled horizontally, but hides the scrollbar if there are not enough children to need it.
4. Lastly, give `section` a `font-size: 0` property. By default, elements that are `display: inline-block` are treated like text, and are thus given an automatic margin. Setting `font-size: 0` on the parent of those elements removes that automatic margin, allowing you to set the margin as you like. Remember, you will need to manually set the font-size of these child items if they contain text.